# Unable to share image on Facebook shar.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, facebook

I am trying to share my website URL with a specific image, but I am unable to do so. I've tried two ways but neither seem to be working.

Method 1:

```
shows black image
    <meta property="og:title" content="Default Description"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="Default Description"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://vmallonline.com/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://vmallonline.com
        /skin/frontend/estore/default/images/logo.png"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
                   a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
                   threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
                   weapons."/>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?
      u=http://myurl.com/">share it
    </a><br />
```

Method 2
This method does not show even image on Facebook

```
<?php
$title=urlencode('Title of Your iFrame Tab');
$url=urlencode('http://myurl.com/');
$summary=urlencode('Custom message that summarizes what your tab is 
about, or just a simple message to tell people to check out your tab.');
$image=urlencode('http://myurl.com/skin/frontend/estore/default/images/logo.png');
?>


<a onClick="window.open(
  'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>
   &amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>
   &amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>
   &amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>
   ','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" 
   href="javascript: void(0)">Insert text or an image here.</a>
```

Comment: Use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to check your Open Graph meta tags. Currently, you don’t seem to have _any_ inside the HTML code of http://vmallonline.com/

Comment: And the sharer does not take _any_ parameters besides the actual URL to share any more (but takes all that data from the OG meta tags of the URL) – that has been mentioned here a lot of times already.